# Chart.js x-axis date label is not in order

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, chart.js

I have a line chart of Chartjs and the data comes from firestore collection. However the x-axis that has d/m/y as label, do not render in order of dates but instead of order of adding the data to the database.
How do I display according to ascending date please?

```
  const labels = this.data.map((x) => x.date);       
     const dateLabels =  
 labels.map(a=>this.datePipe.transform(a.toDate(), 'dd/mm/yyyy'));     
     const ageLabels = this.data.map((x) => x.age);   


       
      if (this.chart)
      this.chart.destroy();    
       this.chart = new Chart('MyChart', {
        type: 'line',
         data: {
         labels: dateLabels,
         datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Age',
            data: ageLabels,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio: 2.5,
      },
    });   
       
      })
```

**Solution**
I have fixed it adding sort().

```
const labels = this.data.map((x) => x.date).sort();
```

Comment: can you share the code where the chart is created?

Comment: Does your data sorted? Please provide sample data to reproduce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I have fixed it adding sort().

```
const labels = this.data.map((x) => x.date).sort();
```